# Is collections.abc.Callable bugged in Python 3.9.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, python-3.9, python-collections

[Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html) includes [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) and deprecates many of the types in the `typing` module in favor of the ones in `collections.abc`, now that they support [`__class_getitem__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0560/). This is the case with for example [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable). To me it would seem that `typing.Callable` and `collections.abc.Callable` should always behave similarly, but they do not.

This simple example results in an error:

```
>>> from typing import Optional
>>> from collections.abc import Callable
>>> def foo(arg: Optional[Callable[[int], int]]) -> None:
...    pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 262, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 339, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem(self, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 463, in Optional
    return Union[arg, type(None)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 262, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 339, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem(self, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 451, in Union
    parameters = _remove_dups_flatten(parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 231, in _remove_dups_flatten
    return tuple(_deduplicate(params))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 205, in _deduplicate
    all_params = set(params)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

but the same error does not happen with `typing.Callable`:

```
>>> from typing import Callable
>>> def foo(arg: Optional[Callable[[int], int]]) -> None:
...    pass
...
>>> # no error
```

The error also doesn't happen if the signature is simplified a bit:

```
>>> from collections.abc import Callable
>>> def foo(arg: Optional[Callable[..., int]]) -> None:
...    pass
...
>>> # no error
>>> def foo(arg: Callable[[int], int]) -> None:
...    pass
...
>>> # no error
```

Is this a bug in Python 3.9 and 3.9.1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `collections.abc.Callable` doesn't work for typing purposes in 3.9.0 and 3.9.1. It was reported [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue43004) and is fixed in [3.9.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#notable-changes-in-python-3-9-2) and 3.10. In the meantime you can continue to use `typing.Callable`.